# Sources about the working of Intel's new 3D transistors

Tags: transistors

I've been searching the net for an explanation about the working mechanism of Intel's new 3D transistor, the most "thorough" explanation I found was [this 4:20 minutes long Intel video](http://www.youtube.com/embed/YIkMaQJSyP8) that doesn't really explain anything.

I'm looking to know about its regions of operation, how the solid state of the device changes in different regions of operation and what improvements does the 3D transistor offers over the 2D.

(Explanations that contain formulas, and professional lingo are preferred)

Comment: Links to videos are not widely appreciated, and especially Olin will not look at it! :-)

Comment: "3D" was just a so nice, fashion, marketing-guy-turn-on word, not to use it there.

Comment: @Telaclavo, no, 3D gates are the future, until graphene or nanotubes don't make it to the market

Comment: @clabacchio I imagine that this technology provides some improvements, and I know in which new sense they say it is 3D, but 3D transistors, strictly speaking, exist since many years ago. See for instance this BJT cross section: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/NPN_BJT_%28Planar%29_Cross-section.svg/300px-NPN_BJT_%28Planar%29_Cross-section.svg.png

Comment: That is not a 3D transistor, just a BJT. 3D is referred to the channel, as you can see in my last link to wiki

Comment: @clabacchio The BJT *is* also a 3D transistor. That was my point. What Intel is starting to commercialize is something that is 3D in a *new* way, but BJTs were already 3D in another way. Even (normal) MOSFETs, are. // BTW, the guys who did the video are real "champs". The channel current does not flow in that direction, the gate should overlap all of the channel, and the smallest possible part of S and D. Also, most are enhancement mode, unlike suggested there.

Comment: @Telaclavo you don't understand my point: 3D transistor in effect means 3d gate, and wiki calls it in the same way. Of course everything is 3d, but if you look at it is the only one which is not planar. Also the BJT has bidimensional interfaces

Comment: Will we need to wear special glasses to see them?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** Look at [Analysis and Design of Tri-Gate MOSFET with 
High Dielectrics Gate](http://www.mecs-press.org/ijisa/ijisa-v4-n5/IJISA-V4-N5-3.pdf):

> In any normal transistor the drain to source current is defined by the equation:
>
> $$
>   I_{DS} = \left( \frac{W}{L} \right) \left( \frac{ \mu C_{ox}}{2} \right)
>   \left[ 2(V_{GS} - V_{T})V_{DS} - {V_{DS}}^2 \right]
>   $$
>
> The drain to source current in tri-gate transistor isp roportional to \$\dfrac{W+2H}{L}\$ ratio. Here H is the width of the transistor and drain to source current is given by the 
>   equation:
>
> $$
>   I_{DS} = \left( \frac{W + 2H}{L} \right) \left( \frac{ \mu C_{ox}}{2} \right)
>   \left[ 2(V_{GS} - V_{T})V_{DS} - {V_{DS}}^2 \right]
>   $$

---

The reason for 3D transistors, which are being studied under different forms, is to increase the interface between the Gate and the channel, without increasing the size of the gate.

The Gate is the terminal that drives the transistor on and off, and acts like a capacitance where charge is stored making the channel conductive. When the gate is charged, it creates an inversion layer between the Source and the Drain, where electrons can flow. This Layer though, is a superficial (you could say planar) area, because it decays exponentially with the distance from the gate.

Since conductivity is proportional to the trasversal section, and given a channel depth (determined by the gate voltage), designers can only work on the width of the channel, which is about the same of the gate width.

A common parameter used to evaluate the problem is the time constant RC: in CMOS technology, a (logical) gate with output resistance R has to switch the next one which has input capacitance C, so to make this fast, the RC product has to be small. As we said, you can halve R doubling the channel width, but doing this you also double C, and the gate before will take twice the time to flip it.

With 3D Gate, you basically "gain" a dimension for the channel, and you can adjust H and W to increase the channel conductivity without proportionally scaling the gate capacitance. Another advantage is that you don't increase the transistor area, which is a significant factor in device cost.

I'm pretty sure that the device works in the same (conceptual) way, just with better performance (but I would say the same leakage), but I can't give you the technical details, and I think nobody can, because it must be a VERY protected technology.

On [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finfet) there is some more literature about the topic. And in the references, you can find [this](http://www.nature.com/news/2011/110506/full/news.2011.274.html), where it's stated:

> **Why is the 3D design better?**
>
> this continued miniaturization has an attendant problem: as the transistor's source and drain get closer together, and as the channel gets smaller, it becomes harder for the gate to control the formation of the inversion layer. Simply put, the distinction between 'off' and 'on' becomes fuzzier.
>
> Having a 3D structure solves this problem. Because it is in contact with three sides of the channel, the gate has much greater control over the inversion layer. This means that the on and off states are more distinct even when the transistor is shrunk.
>
> **Did Intel invent the 3D transistor?**
>
> The Tri-Gate design is essentially a variant of a 'FinFET' 3D structure developed in the late 1990s by Chenming Hu and his colleagues at the University of California, Berkeley. Other chip manufacturers such as IBM, Samsung and TSMC are all working on 3D designs, but are not expected to put them into production until at least the next generation of miniaturization, after 22 nanometres.

Comment: I meant by that sentence that I want to know where charge carriers are going, how and why they do it. How the channel is made, how the doping of the material changes. in the movie the charge flows in the wrong direction, and no explanation is given why should a 3D channel should form when it seems that the source and drain are 2D.

I want to see sources that are on the level of 2nd or 3rd year course of a Bsc at electrical engineering,

Comment: How do they patent without disclosing?

Comment: @Telaclavo I think they don't patent, it's more an industrial secret. The technology is more valuable than the rights over the idea

Comment: @IlyaMelamed you're asking too much; if you understand planar MOSFET technology, you'll understand this better, but you can't ask detailed informations about a developing technology

Comment: @clabacchio Not sure. When you patent something, you don't need to demonstrate or even say what's the benefit of it, nor show an analysis. You just need to say what you want to patent. Now that I've seen the video, I could go and patent that shape for the gate and the channel. I'd say they have protected their IP, and not only by keeping it secret.

Comment: @Telaclavo maybe the 3D gate is patented, but it's nothing new, it's an old thing in research; Intel AFAIK has been the first to implement it in large scale, and most likely until now is the only one with access to that technology

Comment: The disclosure in a patent application needs to "teach" someone of ordinary skill in the field how to make and use the invention. Secret sauce can't be held back. The physics behind the theory of operation should usually be presented but is not actually needed. Sometimes the inventor does not actually know why something works, only that it does.

Answer (score 1):

Intel and other leading semiconductor firms typically present recent results at conferences. Many of the major conferences are under the auspices of IEEE, like IEDM, VLSI Symposia, and ISSCC. If you have IEEE journal access, you can search conference proceedings through [IEEE Xplore](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/) (try "intel trigate"). However you will probably not find too many details about Intel's devices in particular. There will generally be I-V curves and other performance data, but Intel et al don't want to give too much away. So you cannot expect a textbook-type explanation of the device physics.

Searching Google Scholar for "trigate" turned up VLSI Symposium presentations from [2003](http://download.intel.com/technology/silicon/tri-gate-transistor-conference-paper-0603.pdf) and [2006](http://download.intel.com/technology/silicon/tri-gate_foils_VLSI_0606.pdf), available directly from Intel. The search also turned up the Intel trigate [patent](http://www.google.com/patents?id=SDC_AAAAEBAJ).

Keep in mind though that there is a whole lot of academic research on "FinFETs" and other 3D device structures similar to Intel's tri-gate transistors. I am not sure if you will be able to find undergraduate-level materials on these topics, though.

Answer (score 0):

Patents and patent applications are a reasonable way to get a lot of detail on specific aspects of technology.To get a patent one must disclose how to make and use the invention. Holding back the secret sauce can get a patent torn up.

Intel has an international patent application called [Techniques and mechanisms for operation of stacked transistors](https://patents.google.com/patent/WO2019005061A1) pending and many other patents granted. If you go to google patents and search for

> "3d transistor"; stacked; fin; Assignee: intel;

you will see many examples. The patent [US 10,121,875](https://patents.google.com/patent/US10121875B1) is over 100 pages long with many of the pages being detailed illustrations.